# sublimetext view run_command appears to have no effect

Tags: python, sublimetext3

In the following code if a text edit needs to be made it is, successfully. If it doesnt need to be made I see the 'try and close' in the console. But the view doesn't close.
I've tried both close and close_file.

```
if not text == orig:
    view.run_command('select_all')
    view.run_command('cut')
    view.run_command('insert_text', {'string': text})
else:
    #no change, close if it wasnt already open
    if not open_stat:
        print('try and close')
        view.run_command('close')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe close is a window command, so try `view.window().run_command("close")`. I'd also run  `window#focus_view` just to make sure it is in focus. Wouldn't want to be closing the wrong view on accident (though I suppose even with that it's possible).

Comment: thats it but completely unintuitive. eg new view into file, but close window ??